# The image disappears in pictureBox in C#

Tags: c#

I have created application with several forms. In one of the form, it takes several images from the webcam and go to next form(Paint Form) for Editing. I made simple paint project for editing images. The images that I took in the previous form will be displayed in the listbox and by clicking on their name, they will be displayed in the picture box. but when try to edit image and draw Empty Square on image, The image disappears. The same thing happens with other controls, such as empty circles and text.i had many search between other questions but The answer is not what I expect and not worked for me. please help.

[image]

```
    string currentPatientDir; 
    
    Bitmap bmp_image;
    Graphics g;
    Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);
    LinearGradientBrush linearBr;
    Boolean fill;
    public string action = "pen";
    public Font font;
    public string text;
    Point start_pnt;
    int width, height, start_pnt_X, start_pnt_Y;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        New_file();
        p.Color = front_def_color.BackColor;
        pictureBox1.Cursor = new Cursor("cross.cur");

        CurrentPatientDirectory();
    }

    void New_file()
    {
        bmp_image = null;
        bmp_image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_image);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height));
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
    }

    private void panel10_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            panel.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        p.Color = front_def_color.BackColor;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color temp_c = back_def_color.BackColor;
        back_def_color.BackColor = front_def_color.BackColor;
        front_def_color.BackColor = temp_c;
        p.Color = front_def_color.BackColor;
    }

    private void panel10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
        front_def_color.BackColor = panel.BackColor;
        p.Color = front_def_color.BackColor;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case "text":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
                        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
                        Bitmap temp_bmp0 = new Bitmap(bmp_image);
                        Graphics temp_g0 = Graphics.FromImage(temp_bmp0);
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height), Color.FromArgb(147, front_def_color.BackColor), Color.FromArgb(147, front_def_color.BackColor), LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        temp_g0.DrawString(text, font, linearBr, e.X, e.Y);
                        pictureBox1.Image = temp_bmp0;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Radius":
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
                    Bitmap temp_bmp = new Bitmap(bmp_image);
                    Graphics temp_g = Graphics.FromImage(temp_bmp);
                    int radius = Math.Max(Math.Abs(start_pnt.X - e.X), Math.Abs(start_pnt.Y - e.Y));
                    if (fill)
                    {
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        temp_g.FillEllipse(linearBr, (float)start_pnt.X - radius, (float)start_pnt.Y - radius, (float)radius * 2, (float)radius * 2);
                    }
                    else
                        temp_g.DrawEllipse(p, (float)start_pnt.X - radius, (float)start_pnt.Y - radius, (float)radius * 2, (float)radius * 2);
                    pictureBox1.Image = temp_bmp;
                    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = radius.ToString();
                    break;
                case "Square width":
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
                    Bitmap temp_bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp_image);
                    Graphics temp_g2 = Graphics.FromImage(temp_bmp2);
                    temp_g2.DrawLine(p, start_pnt, new Point(e.X, start_pnt.Y));
                    start_pnt_X = Math.Min(e.X, start_pnt.X);
                    width = Math.Abs(e.X - start_pnt.X);
                    pictureBox1.Image = temp_bmp2;
                    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = width.ToString() + "×" + height.ToString();
                    break;
                case "Square length":
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
                    Bitmap temp_bmp3 = new Bitmap(bmp_image);
                    Graphics temp_g3 = Graphics.FromImage(temp_bmp3);
                    height = Math.Abs(e.Y - start_pnt.Y);
                    start_pnt_Y = Math.Min(e.Y, start_pnt.Y);
                    if (fill)
                    {
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        temp_g3.FillRectangle(linearBr, new Rectangle(start_pnt_X, start_pnt_Y, width, height));
                    }
                    else
                        temp_g3.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(start_pnt_X, start_pnt_Y, width, height));
                    pictureBox1.Image = temp_bmp3;
                    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = width.ToString() + "×" + height.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void panel14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
        panel14.BorderStyle = panel11.BorderStyle = panel12.BorderStyle = panel13.BorderStyle = panel14.BorderStyle = panel15.BorderStyle = panel16.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        p.Width = int.Parse(panel.Tag.ToString());
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Set_border(pictureBox2);
        action = "text";
        Add_string addStr = new Add_string(font, text);
        addStr.Tag = this;
        addStr.ShowDialog();
    }
    //------------------------------------------- SetBorder
    void Set_border(PictureBox picB)
    {
        pictureBox2.BorderStyle = pictureBox3.BorderStyle = pictureBox4.BorderStyle = pictureBox5.BorderStyle = pictureBox6.BorderStyle = pictureBox7.BorderStyle = pictureBox8.BorderStyle = pictureBox9.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        picB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case "text":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        g.DrawString(text, font, linearBr, e.X, e.Y);
                    }
                    break;
                case "start point ":
                    start_pnt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                    action = "line";
                    break;
                case "line":
                    linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, 4, 4), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                    g.DrawLine(p, start_pnt, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    start_pnt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                    break;
                case "The center point of the circle":
                    start_pnt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                    action = "Radius";
                    break;
                case "Radius":
                    int radius = Math.Max(Math.Abs(start_pnt.X - e.X), Math.Abs(start_pnt.Y - e.Y));
                    if (fill)
                    {
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        g.FillEllipse(linearBr, (float)start_pnt.X - radius, (float)start_pnt.Y - radius, (float)radius * 2, (float)radius * 2);
                    }
                    else
                        g.DrawEllipse(p, (float)start_pnt.X - radius, (float)start_pnt.Y - radius, (float)radius * 2, (float)radius * 2);
                    action = "The center point of the circle";
                    break;
                case "Square Begin":
                    start_pnt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                    action = "Square width";
                    break;
                case "Square width ":
                    action = "Square length";
                    break;
                case "Square length":
                    if (fill)
                    {
                        linearBr = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_image.Width, bmp_image.Height), front_def_color.BackColor, front_def_color.BackColor, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
                        g.FillRectangle(linearBr, new Rectangle(start_pnt_X, start_pnt_Y, width, height));
                    }
                    else
                        g.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(start_pnt_X, start_pnt_Y, width, height));
                    action = "square begin";
                    break;

            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp_image;
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Set_border(pictureBox6);
        action = "The center point of the circle";
        fill = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Set_border(pictureBox7);
        action = "Square Begin";
        fill = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Enter Text";
    } 

    private void pictureBox6_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "drawing empty circles ";
    }

    private void pictureBox7_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "drawing Empty Square ";
    }           


    private void panel16_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = (Panel)sender;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "pen Siz " + p.Tag.ToString();
    }

    private void pictureBox8_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
    }

    private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "change front and back color";
    }
            
    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("want to Exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
            e.Cancel = false;
        else e.Cancel = true;
    }      

    // Hamed  نمایش عکسای گرفته شده از لیست باکس داخل پیکچرباکس    
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var selectedImage = listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( selectedImage) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPatientDir))
            {
                var patientFullPath = Path.Combine(currentPatientDir, selectedImage);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(patientFullPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception errorMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + errorMessage.Message + "" + errorMessage.Source);
        }
    }

    public void textBoxPatientFolderPath(string Value)
    {
        txtPatientFolderPath.Text = Value;
    }

    // متد برای پر کردن لیست باکس فایل های داخل فولدر
    public void CurrentPatientDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            currentPatientDir = txtPatientFolderPath.Text;
                            
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentPatientDir);

            var files = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(c => (c.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || c.Extension.Equals(".jpeg")));
            foreach (var images in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(images.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is an Error: " + ex.Message + "" + ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to "Graphics temp_g2" dispose after you are done, then calling pictureBox1.Refresh() ?

Comment: @Ugur thanks but where i should add "pictureBox1.Refresh()" ? i add project here. https://github.com/bolikaka/PaintHamed.git

Comment: where you update the image

Comment: i can't Edit image before update. images Capture in previous form and show in listbox in myPaint form. listbox give it from folder.

Comment: @Ugur did you mean in Form_Load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Event `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, after

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(patientFullPath);
```

just add:

```
bmp_image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_image);
```